# How can I restrict my Google Search's results to n number of sites? (n>1)

Tags: google-search

I know I can use `site:` to restrict my search result to a particular site. How can I restrict my search on more particular sites?

Comment: How to [refine web searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en). I don't know if you're meaning to search for a particular string across many sites or what. The question is a bit too broad. Hopefully the link answers some questions for you.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this page. But it can only designate to one site, or one particular domain extension. Wondering whether I can refine the result by a list of sites.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use **OR** operator

example: **`matrix site:youtube.com OR site:imdb.com`**